# Choosing an epsilon when comparing floating point numbers across different systems

Tags: unit-testing, floating-point

I am transcribing thousands of lines of computational code from MATLAB to C++. I don't fully understand the math myself, but I can run it with MATLAB, assume it's correct, and compare the results to my C++ code.

The issue is that the precision I get is very inconsistent. Sometimes MATLAB gives me four significant digits for a number on the order of 1e6, so I have to use an epsilon of 100. Other times, I will be using an epsilon of 1e-3, but then suddenly there will be one value that just different enough to require me to bump it up to 1e-2.

Are there any potential problems with adjusting the epsilon of my tests to a passing value? Is there a more reliable approach?

Comment: Are you somehow using 8 bit floats, or is the algorithm numerically unstable? Four significant digits is pretty terrible in most circumstances, and only *two* is hilariously depressingly bad.

Comment: With different systems, do you mean different only MATLAB vs. "one specific C++ compiler", or also different hardware?

Comment: Doc Brown: I'll be running different hardware in the future, but the issue is present using MATLAB vs one C++ compiler on the same computer.

Comment: delnan: I believe the issues stems from MATLAB only display 4 significant digits, rather than the numbers just being wrong. Although, this suggests that I could just write a function to determine an epsilon from the order of the number and available significant digits....

Comment: @JETM Okay so you only compare four digits (which is kinda silly tbh) but one or two of those are still off? Are you perhaps taking four-digit output from MATLAB at some point and put it back in the C++ program?

Comment: @delnan So if MATLAB gives me 0.1234, and C++ gives 0.1233652, the difference is < 1e-4. But when I start getting higher numbers like 10.37, and C++ gives 10.3668, I'm automatically going to have a larger difference.

Comment: Have you tried convincing MATLAB to output more digits?

Comment: *I believe the issues stems from MATLAB only display 4 significant digits*  That may be Matlab's default but you can over-ride it ...

Comment: @CodesInChaos That actually fixed everything!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments we exchanged, it seems you are not just unfamiliar with the maths, but also with basic numeric computing discipline.

First, for god's sake, don't automatically pick an epsilon to makes your tests "pass". If you fudge the epsilons until the error is below epsilon, your tests don't test anything at all and you may ignore really bad precision problems (perhaps even a *wrong algorithm* if it happens to produce similar results in your test cases).

Instead, pick a-priori reasonable epsilons *and stick to them*. If your get greater errors than you need or expect, that means you need to **fix your code, not lower your expectations**. Sadly, what expectations are "reasonable" depends on the application and the algorithm, but by default I'd expect, say, a relative error of less than 1e-12 if the floats are 64 bits.

Second, the keyword is *relative* error. Absolute error is, as you've seen, very sensitive to the magnitude of the values, and thus often useless. Moreover, due to how floating point works, there is a fixed relative error that you can't beat unless you happen to produce the *exact* same bit pattern (for 64 bit floats, this is about 1e-17). Thus, if numbers are large enough, you will find that your absolute error is either zero (unlikely) or quite large, even though the calculation may be only be off by one unit in the last place (ULP).

For this, you should also force MATLAB to output more digits (17 is the maximum number that makes sense for 64 bit floats). Oh, and relative error calculations can be quite tricky, as @CodeInChaos also points out, so you may want to rely on existing algorithms that handle edge cases better than the naive approaches, such as http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

Answer (score 2):

Using [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) floating points in both programs (which is the standard in MATLAB) on the same hardware for a deterministic algorithm is a minimum requirement to get similar results in both programs, assumed you are very pedantic in implementing each computational operation from your MATLAB program in a 1:1 fashion in your C++ program.

However, you need to understand the math you are doing at least to the point where you are sure your algorithms do not show some unstable or [chaotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory) behaviour, otherwise the slightest difference in some input values or internal implementation can result in a much bigger difference for the results than you might expect. I have seen these kind of effects, for example, even in **the same** program, with a **deterministic** algorithm, just by compiling and running it in "debug" mode vs. "release" mode.

The best recommendation I can give you for such a situation is extensive logging of intermediate values in both programs and compare the results to find out which operations behave differently, so you can adapt your C++ implementation and make it behave more similar to the MATLAB code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a relative error.

```
abs(actual / correct - 1) < epsilon
```

But this doesn't work well if `correct` is very small. So you might have both an absolute and relative epsilon, accepting the result if it's smaller than at least one of them.

Comment: While relative error eventually becomes problematic at the very end of the scale, there are multiple possible ways to calculate relative errors, some of which work quite well when others fail. For example, `abs((actual - correct) / correct) < epsilon` might be more robust. I would rather try a different formula before I resort to absolute error. (Also, in some languages/tool suites you have the option of computing the relative error exactly, e.g. using bignum fractions.)

Comment: @delnan I'm more worried about the case where the absolute error in the actual computation is very small, yet the relative error is big and not about errors in the error computation. Still it's probably a good idea to only switch to absolute errors where it fits the problem, instead of using a comparison function which switches automatically.

Comment: Since we always have 53 bits of precision, and precision guarantees for individual operations are all in relative error, *identical* inputs should give relatively close results. I admit that sometimes, it may be more practical to accept a big relative difference when the term as a whole is neglectible, but even then I would rather phrase this in terms of a looser relative error bound than also introduce an absolute error bar. (That said, we seem to be in violent agreement so let's call it quits.)